# Spring Boot 2 JUnit Test for rest api failed at 'jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint':

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-test

I am writing Junit test for spring boot service ,for testing api call,but It failed to run throwing following exception

```
Caused by:org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceServerConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'entryPoint'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
```

**Junit Test:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public class ServiceTest {

  @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext wac;

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build(); 
    }

        @Test
        public void validateApiCall() throws Exception {
            String token = "Bearer xxxxxxxx";   
         mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("http://localhost::8060/api").header("Authorization", token)).andExpect(status().isOk());


        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by autowiring `javax.servlet.Filter[]` this way

```
        @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
        @SpringBootTest
        @ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
        @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
        public class ServiceTest {

          @Autowired
          protected WebApplicationContext wac;

          @Autowired
          private javax.servlet.Filter[] springSecurityFilterChain;

          @MockBean private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwt;

          protected MockMvc mockMvc;

          @Before
          public void setup() {
              MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
              mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain).build();
            }

                @Test
                public void validateApiCall() throws Exception {
                    String token = "Bearer xxxxxxxx";   

 mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("http://localhost::8060/api").header("Authorization", token)).andExpect(status().isOk());


                }
        }
```